My second monitor freezes every time Ubuntu asks for a password
I am new to Linux. My second monitor freezes every time Ubuntu asks for a password. I have a work around by unplugging and plugging my monitor back in but I am getting frustrated. I am not even sure where to start.
I switched to Ubuntu from Windows 11 because I found out about a bunch of spyware and adware on it but now I am just lost. Nothing is the same. I don't even know what a terminal or a sudo is.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Release: 24.04 Codename: noble
This is the computer I have
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CT453LL8
The monitor is about the same size as my regular monitor. It connects with an HDMI cable and a separate USB-C cable for power.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please include your version of Ubuntu, hardware specs, GPU, graphics, drivers, method of connecting the extra monitor like display port or hdmi and anything else relevant to your display. Thanks.

It may also help if you're specific with details... what password?  At greeter or login (ie. when using the DM or Display Manager) my own system only shows images/logins on the three screens connected to my first GPU (ie. two monitors connected to the second GPU are dark), but once logged in I can use all displays.  We currently don't know what Ubuntu product you're asking about (see prior comment), what release etc either.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble

I have this kind of computer: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0CT453LL8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1

I take you're using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop?? and not Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server? or one of the flavors, as you've not yet said (ie. which 24.04 product)

What exactly do you mean by monitor being freezed? What happens to the cursor? Also, please elaborate on what kind of password dialog.
